# MySQL Parent details if it is a child account

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table with data like the following

```
id    name      created         parent
------------------------------------------------
1     Alpha     11385209583     0
2     Bravo     11385209619     0
3     Bravo-A   11385209701     2
4     Bravo-B   11385209777     2
```

such that Bravo-A and Bravo-B are children of Bravo.

There is another table with email addresses in it (accounts a JOIN emails e ON a.id = e.account_id), but only parent accounts have emails. That is to say, Bravo-A's email is Bravo's.

If I have the accounts.id number, is it possible to write a query that would give me the emails.email field for the correct account (where account_id = 1 when id is 1, account_id = 2 when id is 2, 3, or 4)?

(My apologies if this is a little verbose or not to the point, I was having trouble verbalizing it!)

Comment: So you want to return Bravo's email if id = 3?

Comment: Can only _top-level_ accounts have e-mails, or all _parent_ accounts (for example, if Bravo-B got some children, could it then have an e-mail)?

Comment: @XavierHolt i think that's the OP want, the parent's email address is also the child's email address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered it myself!

```
SELECT a.id, e.email 
FROM account a 
         INNER JOIN emails.e 
              ON e.account_id = IF(a.parent <> 0, a.parent, a.id)
```

The thing I find with SQL is that there is always a more elegant way!

Answer (score 4):

Why not join `acount`'s  `parent` column to the `email`?

```
SELECT  a.*, 
        e.emailadd as parentEAdd, 
        COALESCE(b.emailadd,'') as ChildEAdd -- can contain null values when 
                                             -- parentID is 0
FROM    `accounts` a 
             INNER JOIN `emails` e 
                  ON a.id = e.account_id
             LEFT JOIN `emails` b
                  ON a.parent = b.account_id
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to put another field in accounts table (say "mail_id"), store each email's id there and do joins based on that field. That way the childs may have the same or different mails if you want